# placed username password on the same page as the destination page using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an admin panel using php. But What i want to do is, when any user click on the home page, first ask their username and password if both are correct then show content of home page other wise not.

Comment: and your question is...? If it's "please write this for me", then please go elsewhere. we are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: @MarcB On fire this morning. #impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using Htaccess password protection.

Create a .htaccess file

```
AuthUserFile /usr/somewhere/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Files"
Require valid-user
```

Create a .htpasswd file (in the path you mentioned above)

```
mark:test1234
```

You don't need PHP thing to do that!

Refer http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

Comment: sk8terboi87 your ans is right but i want to crate dynamically users and all the records comes from database

Comment: @NikunjJagad: I'm not sure it is possible if you're doing with htpasswd file. But, may be if we fetch a record in index.php & somehow pass to htpasswd it might be... but, seriously i don't if that is possible.

Comment: sk8terboi87:its ok,and thank you for ans,your blog is nice